# Trying to install composer package but laravel is out of date

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM via

`$ composer require brozot/laravel-fcm` but i get a ton of errors. Here is what shows up in the error log when I run it:

```
composer require brozot/laravel-fcm
Using version ^1.2 for brozot/laravel-fcm
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - brozot/laravel-fcm v1.2.0 requires illuminate/support >=5.0.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28].
    - brozot/laravel-fcm v1.2.1 requires illuminate/support >=5.0.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28].
    - brozot/laravel-fcm v1.2.2 requires illuminate/support 5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28].
    - brozot/laravel-fcm v1.2.3 requires illuminate/support 5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28].
    - brozot/laravel-fcm v1.2.4 requires illuminate/support 5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28].
    - brozot/laravel-fcm v1.2.5 requires illuminate/support 5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28].
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v4.2.22, required as 4.2.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.22].
    - Installation request for brozot/laravel-fcm ^1.2 -> satisfiable by brozot/laravel-fcm[v1.2.0, v1.2.1, v1.2.2, v1.2.3, v1.2.4, v1.2.5].
```

Yeah, there is alot going on. I will also share my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "5.7.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
        "zizaco/entrust": "1.2.*@dev",
        "mandrill/mandrill": "1.0.54",
        "curl/curl": "1.2.0",
        "artdarek/oauth-4-laravel": "1.0.5",
        "abraham/twitteroauth": "0.7.2",
        "davibennun/laravel-push-notification": "dev-master",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "4.4.*",
        "intervention/image": "2.1.3",
        "mockery/mockery" : "0.9.4",
        "nesbot/carbon" : "1.*",
        "sendgrid/sendgrid" : "4.0.*",
        "twilio/sdk" : "5.8.0",
        "php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "^0.6.1",
        "sinergi/browser-detector" : "6.1.2",
        "google/apiclient" : "2.*",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^0.7.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel" : "1.3.10"
    },
    "require-dev" : {
        "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/helpers",
            "app/jobs"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

I really need this plugin installed, I just cannot figure out why it is freaking out. I am new to Laravel, so its error logs are still a little new to me. Is there a quick way to auto update my dependencies or anything? Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Every version of the package seems to require Laravel > 5.2 https://packagist.org/packages/brozot/laravel-fcm#v0.9.0  You could open an issue in git and ask them if there is any way the package can support v4 Laravel, but likely you'll need to update Laravel to use this package.

Answer (score 1):

The package you are trying to install is using laravel 5. Look here to find the dependency of the package:

> https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM/blob/master/composer.json#L23
>
> https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM/blob/master/composer.json#L15

It is telling composer to use `laravel 5.2` and `illuminate/support > 5`

**Note:**

The developer has already told that this package won't simply work in Laravel 4.

> https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM/issues/2

**His Comment :**

> I'm sorry but this package is constructed to work with Laravel > 5.
>   Unfortunately it can't work with Laravel 4.2 simply. I will note this constraint in the documentation.

You could use these package for `php` support as there is `no laravel 4` version of library available.

> https://github.com/sngrl/php-firebase-cloud-messaging
>
> https://github.com/Paragraph1/php-fcm

Also i couldn't find any php version of firebase docs in the official site.

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/

There is only `javascript` version for web.

There might be php version before but i am not sure they support php now.

Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the PHP idea. But I am having to schedule the notifications to go out at certain times, is this able to do within the php of a laravel project? If so, it might just work

Comment: @Austin Laravel is also built on top of php so, if there is less feature than ou want doing some workaround you could implement the part using php and laravel features.

Comment: Okay, I have built a command in laravel to get the token out of MySQL and stuff, now all I have to do is call the FCM plugin. Any tips?

Comment: @Austin Sorry, no idea on FCM. Never used FCM. Other might help you.

Comment: composer require apility/laravel-fcm
 this helped me